Ubuntu Pro on a VirtualBox vm
I have a general question about using an Ubuntu vm on VirtualBox.
Is it okay to activate and use Ubuntu Pro on an Ubuntu VM in CISCO VirtualBox?

VirtualBox is an Oracle product and not Cisco, Cisco offers NFV for virtualization

This question is similar to: What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The link you provided to the other thread addressed my question.  I was able to pick up from a FAQ that you only really need to use Ubuntu Pro if your system NEEDS to meet regulatory requirements. I'll dig into the thread some more. Thank you for clarifying about the CISCO Oracle mismatch. Greatly appreciated.
